# Indexing array "Assign" with type dexpr int not supported by this algorithm

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl, ilog

My question is [similar to one already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710894/cplex-opl-using-decision-variable-as-array-index), but there was not an answer (at least not one accepted nor suitable).

I am attempting to make a constraint, which I've simplified below:

```
dexpr int startingWeekChanges[p in People] = 7 * y + 1;
```

...

```
for(p in People){
    Assign[startingWeekChanges[p]] == 1;
}
```

But I see this is not allowed (error message being "Indexing array "Assign" with type dexpr int not supported by this algorithm").

I can't change over to constraint programming. Is there an alternative strategy to get by this?

Comment: Explaining why exactly the answers provided in the question you linked would go a long way towards helping others provide the answer that you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this might do the trick:

```
forall (i in IndexSetForAssign)
   Assign[i] == (sum (p in People) (startingWeekChanges[p] == i) >= 1);
```

It sets `Assign[i]` to 1 if at least one `startingWeekChanges[p]` has the value `i`. If not then it sets `Assign[i]` to 0.

The expressions above exploit the fact that you can use the truth value (1 if true, 0 otherwise) of a constraint for modeling.

Comment: This looks very promising but I'm a little confused - what exactly is IndexSetForAssign? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `IndexSetForAssign` is the index set you used when you defined `Assign`. Assuming you did `dvar int Assign[I]` this would just be `I`.

Comment: Ah, the problem is my simplification, as Assign is actually 4 dimensional. I now have that part working thanks to your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

At https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=7bb1e7ff-ec3a-4e79-a8c4-c20050dfad0c&ps=25 I answered the same question and gave an example.

range r=1..5;

```
float value[r]=[2,3,4.5,1,0];
dvar int i in 1..5;
dexpr int j=6-i;

maximize sum(k in r) value[k]*(k==j);
subject to
{

}

execute
{
writeln("i=",i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to define an expression as the value of an array indexed by a variable.  This is called the *element constraint* [1] and is only available in the context of Constraint Programming, as a Linear Programming solver can't cope with such constraints.

[1] https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_constraints_types_inCP.html#usropllangref.uss_langref_constraints.1073721__section1319017294580